# How to add custom markers using google maps directions api in react js

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-map-react

**Tech Stack** - Google Map Directions Api, React JS, etc.

**Problem Statement** - Using google maps direction Api's i am drawing 3 pins i.e. origin, waypoints and destination. I am able to plot all these of these but unable to add custom markers to each of these. Any help/suggestion shall be really appreciated: -

**Code Snippet: -**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    withGoogleMap,
    withScriptjs,
    GoogleMap,
    DirectionsRenderer
} from "react-google-maps";

class Map extends Component {
    state = {
        directions: null
    };

componentDidMount() {
        const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        const origin = { lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298, icon: 'https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/map-marker-icon-600x-map-marker-11562939743ayfahlvygl.png' };
        const destination = { lat: 41.756795, lng: -78.954298, icon: 'https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/map-marker-icon-600x-map-marker-11562939743ayfahlvygl.png' };

   directionsService.route({
            origin: origin,
            destination: destination,
            waypoints: [{
                location: new google.maps.LatLng(42.756795, -78.954298, 'https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/map-marker-icon-600x-map-marker-11562939743ayfahlvygl.png'),
                stopover: false
            }],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        },
            (result, status) => {
                if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    this.setState({
                        directions: result
                    });
                } else {
                    console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
                }
            }
   );
    }
  render() {
        const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap(props => (
            <GoogleMap
                defaultCenter={{ lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 }}
                defaultZoom={13}
            >
                <DirectionsRenderer
                    directions={this.state.directions}
                />
            </GoogleMap>
        ));

        return (
            <div>
                <GoogleMapExample
                    containerElement={<div style={{ height: `500px`, width: "500px" }} />}
                    mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Map;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-google-maps` has a [`Marker`](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#marker) component that you can use.

```
<GoogleMap
  defaultCenter={{ lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 }}
  defaultZoom={13}
>
  <DirectionsRenderer
    directions={this.state.directions}
  />
  <Marker location={{ lat: x, lng: y }} />
</GoogleMap>
```

Comment: Thanks Will for your answer. Can you please help on how do i customize the icon of the marker example for origin we need to show 'https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/map-marker-icon-600x-map-marker-11562939743ayfahlvygl.png'?

Comment: If you go to the link on `Marker` in the answer, you'll find all the props. I believe there is an `icon` property, which you should be able to assign that image to.

Comment: render() {
        const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap(props => (
            <GoogleMap
                defaultCenter={{ lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 }}
                defaultZoom={13}
            >
                <DirectionsRenderer
                    directions={this.state.directions}
                />
            <Marker icon="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/map-marker-icon-600x-map-marker-11562939743ayfahlvygl.png" location={{ lat: 42.756795, lng: -78.954298 }} />
            </GoogleMap>

        ));

Comment: i updated with the above code but did not work, please help on the same

Comment: {
      marker_arr.map((item, i) => (
        <Marker
          key={i}
          icon={{
            url: item.url,
            // anchor: new google.maps.Point(item.lat, item.lng),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(37, 37),
          }}
          position={{
            lat: item.lat,
            lng: item.lng,
          }}
        />
      ))
}

Comment: Markers are visible now using the above code, but i see the default google marker also visible example 'A' 'B'. How can i hide/remove this?